# Hiding Android title bar in Xamarin has a delay

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm trying to hide the title bar in a Xamarin Android project, with this as the first line of code in Activity.OnCreate:

```
Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle)
```

However, the title still shows briefly and THEN disappears. I don't want it to show at all - is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Use a theme instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this in a theme so it is created with no title **before** being shown:

**Add a Theme:**

'Resources/values/NoTitleTheme.xml'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.NoTitle" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

**Use the Theme:**

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.NoTitle", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class PlayScriptActivity : Activity
```